# git commit error message

Tags: git, git-commit

When I write a command line:

```
git commit -m ™Initial commit™
```

I got an error:

```
error: pathspec '"commit\342\204\242"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably those hilarious ™ trademark symbols:

```
$ echo -e "\0342\0204\0242"
™
```

Try typing in, by hand, `git commit -m "initial commit"`, and using the standard `"` quotes -- ASCII octal 042, decimal 34, hex 0x22.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is because there is no file that git could be put into the repository.

Create an empty file (for example .gitlock), and then run this command before committing:

```
git add .gitlock
```